# ADB debugging stopped working, Samsung S21, Macos, Catalina

Tags: macos, android, adb

My primary testing device has stopped working over adb on macos catalina. I have done a lot of troubleshooting that will be detailed out below.

TLDR; The device works fine on another desktop, and on the mac in parallels (windows 10). Other devices also work.

Update:
I fully restored from a Time Machine backup from a few weeks ago. This would have been when things were working, but it still doesn't work. I think this let's us know that it's a problem on the android device.

Update 2:
I reset the S21 to factory settings (what a pain to re-setup). Made no difference. There was an update recently, so I tried using ODIN to flash to the previous update. No difference.

I'm still stumped as to which device is the culprit.

Update 3:
This comes out in the macbook logs, in /var/log/system.log every time I turn on debug mode.

> xpcproxy[3538]: libcoreservices: _dirhelper_userdir: 557: bootstrap_look_up returned (ipc/send) invalid destination port
> xpcproxy[3539]: libcoreservices: _dirhelper_userdir: 557: bootstrap_look_up returned (ipc/send) invalid destination port

Environment:
2019 Macbook Pro, Catalina (updating the OS is not an option at this time)
Samsung S21

Steps to show the issue:

1. Turn off USB debugging
2. Stop adb - adb kill-server
3. Plug in S21
4. See that S21 is available for file transfer
5. Start adb - adb start-server
6. File transfer drops off, cannot transfer files
7. adb devices - lists nothing

Reboot devices:

1. Reboot mac
2. Reboot S21
3. No difference

Different USB ports:

1. Try four different USB hubs
2. Try all four USB-C ports
3. Try a USB-C dock
4. No difference

Reinstall adb:

1. In android studio uncheck the SDK tools and let it uninstall
2. Check the SDK tools and let it install
3. Start adb
4. No difference

Try adb separately:

1. Download SDK tools 31 for mac
2. Stop and start adb
3. No differences
4. Download SDK tools 30 for mac
5. Stop and start adb
6. No difference

Try windows on mac:

1. Start up Parallels with Windows 10
2. Connect device
3. adb works perfectly

Try another machine, windows:

1. Start up windows 10 desktop
2. Connect device
3. adb works perfectly

Try another device:

1. Connect Xiaomi MI9T
2. adb works fine

Comment: **What worked for me was:** https://stackoverflow.com/a/28211161/8740349